# The Organization Browser comes up empty if added to the mysite homepage

Tags: 2010, web-part, my-site, organization-browser

Adding the Organization Browser webpart to the My Profile page works fine, but it comes empty when added to the MySites homepage. Silverlight view shows empty (however the 4 arrows do exist and can be seen when hovered over) and Html view throws a javascript error (Children is invalid).

Any clues?

Comment: I am faced with the same issue any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Somethings to check:

Is your User Profile Sync working fine? Have you setup UPS sync services and are they working correctly?
What service account is it running under? 
Is that service account part of Local Administrator group?